# Button shoud be all the time clicked even when I'm in 2nd activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have a question, in my aplication I have button when he is click on, then start counting time. And when I go to another activity button is off and stop counting time. How to make that when I'm in another activity button is still clicked and counting time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onPause() {
    //save clicked state and counting time.
}

public void onResume() {
    //restore clicked state and counting time.
}
```